# How to display range value in div on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the dynamically value of range slider in div id="output" when on change. Thanks

```
     <div id="outcome_main_section">
        <div id="outcome_section_2">
            <div id="range_added_section"></div>

            <input type="submit" name="btn_submit"> 
            <input type="button" class="add_range" value="Add Range">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
 $('body').on("change",".range_slider",function (){

    var range_value = $(this).val();

 });



$('body').on("click",".add_range",function(){

$('#range_added_section').append
(
    $(
        '<div id="output"></div>' + 
        '<input class="range_slider" type="range" min="1" max="100"        value="1" step="1" name="range_value[range_value][]" >'
     )
);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `className` for `id` at `'<div id="output"></div>'` to prevent duplicate `id` being appended to document at each click of `.add_range` elements; utilize `.prev()`, `.text()` within `change` event for `.range_slider` to select previous `.output` element to set text to `value` of next element sibling `input type="range"`

```js
$('body').on("change", ".range_slider", function() {
  var range_value = $(this).val();
  $(this).prev(".output").text(range_value)
});



$('body').on("click", ".add_range", function() {
  $('#range_added_section').append(
    $(
      '<div class=output></div>' +
      '<input class=range_slider type=range ' +
      'min=1 max=100 value=1 step=1 name=range_value[range_value][] >'
    )
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="add_range">add range</div>
<div id="range_added_section"></div>
```

Comment: It takes me 2hrs to get the output but didn't work. Thanks!